# Ionic setting screen orientation in config.xml does not lock the orientation

Tags: android, ionic-framework, locking, screen-orientation

I am using Ionic and am trying to lock the screen orientation in landscape mode using:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

in the `config.xml` file.

This works fine and brings up the app in landscape mode. However, while the app is running if I get a notification from another app, for example a notification from "Clean Master" app in Android that asks me if I want to delete unneeded apk file, will change the orientation to portrait.

Is there a way to make sure the app orientation never changes, even with an interrupt from another app?

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I never use it but it can maybe solve your problem : https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock

Comment: Thanks, this is a good link, but I prefer not to use any additional plugin if possible.